# A Program that have 20 questions and asks 5 of them randomly

Tags: c#

As a school project my task is writing a c# code that asks 5 different randomly choosen questions out of 20 questions that i set before (not math questions they are strings)

But i couldnt find a way to do it without using 20 switch cases which im not allowed to do

can anybody give me some tips i really need some help

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Try writing some code.  One idea would be to put the questions in an array and remove them from the array once the question was asked.

Comment: so far all i have is 2 arrays one of them are for the questions and other is for the answers

Comment: It'd probably be better to put them into one class, like a class with a string for question, then an array of answers.  Then one approach would be to use Random as people are suggesting and as you pick questions, null them out of the list and make sure in later picks that you don't pick null questions.

Comment: Also, look into the modulus operator '%' to understand how Random.Next with the range works.

Answer (score 1):

Put the 20 questions in a list or similar data structure.

Choose an index (between 0 and "list length") at random.
Take the question at that list index, remove question from list.

Repeat (with the now smaller list) until you have 5 questions.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `Random` and generate question id, then use this id to access array of questions.

```
Random random = new Random();
int id = random.Next(0, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you using a random seems like a great idea will try it thank you so much